# Targeting last row in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have 2 column design and I am trying to target last element on the right side and last elements on the bottom so I can remove margin.

I know how I can do it. This is the way I used:

```
.connection-container:nth-child(2n){ margin-right: 0; }

.connection-container:nth-child(2n+1):nth-last-child(-n+2),
.connection-container:nth-child(2n+1):nth-last-child(-n+2) ~ .connection-container{
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Remove the margin of last 2 elements */
}
```

This method works. But the problem is I have another div, which is title. Because of that title, this code doesn't work.

```
.section-container.clearfix
  .section-title= 'Connections'

  - if @profile.friends.size > 0
    - @profile.friends.each do |friend|
      .connection-container.clearfix.pull-left
        .connection-photo.pull-left
          = image_tag friend.photo.url(:thumb)
        .connection-details.pull-left
          .connection-info= link_to "#{friend.first_name} #{friend.last_name}", profile_path(friend.id)
          .connection-info= friend.school
          .connection-info= friend.program
        .connection-buttons.pull-left
          = display_connections_buttons(friend)
```

How can I make this css code work with title? I tried many thing but didn't work.

Thank you.

**edit**

```
<div class="section-container clearfix">
  <div class="section-title">Connections</div>
  <% if @profile.friends.size > 0 %>
    <% @profile.friends.each do |friend| %>
      <div class="connection-container clearfix pull-left">
        <div class="connection-photo pull-left">
          <%= image_tag friend.photo.url(:thumb) %>
        </div>
        <div class="connection-details pull-left">
          <div class="connection-info">
            <%= link_to "#{friend.first_name} #{friend.last_name}", profile_path(friend.id) %>
          </div>
          <div class="connection-info">
            <%= friend.school %>
          </div>
          <div class="connection-info">
            <%= friend.program %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="connection-buttons pull-left">
          <%= display_connections_buttons(friend) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML code. Dynamic code is of little value in this situation. A demo of your issue will be a lot better.

Comment: @ManojKumar I posted.

Comment: Can't you just use the `:last-of-type()` CSS selector?

Comment: Still I don't think we can get the column design with your current code. Check your browser and copy the code.

Comment: @Jonathan: No - these are all divs.

Comment: @cyonder can you please browse that page as a normal user then extract the source?